# How can I automatically add the data of one cell to another cell on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to automatically add the data I get from a survey into another sheet on the same document, however, what I want to do is have it added each time I get a response. I want it to continuously do this, but I have no idea where to start.

I am aiming for it to end up something like this:

```
Date of Entry| Ticket# | Content(s) | Has it arrived?
1/1/20         10214     Keyboard     No
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think you can connect your sheet to Forms. Have you read this? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2917686?hl=en

Comment: In addition to @Calculuswhiz comment, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention

> ...automatically add the data I get from a survey into another sheet on the same document... each time I get a response. I want it to continuously do this

There's more than one way to cook an egg.

The easiest one in your case being:

In cell `A1` of your new sheet place the following formula

```
=INDEX('Form responses 1'!A1:I)
```

*(Please adjust ranges/names to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)

Comment: Just a quick question, if I wanted to do this, but add a requirement like a certain cell has to contain x how would I do that?

Comment: It depends on like, where that cell is, will it stay there, will there be more than one x, etc. In other words we would need much more info in order to answer your comment.

Comment: There would be one requirement for it to display and it would stay there. For example: If we get a response that says it is going to WEST, I want it to index all responses heading to WEST

Comment: Just noticed your [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64280980/1527780). So I guess it is answered?

Comment: You could try using a `QUERY` or an `IF` function in a formula. As I said I need more info. Give me an image with more data or a sheet or something usable. Otherwise it will just be a hit and miss answer. :/