# How can I check if a certain ticket # is present in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that shows if certain shipments of parts have arrived yet, but I am stuck on the IF Statement. Basically, I want it to check if a certain ticket number is present in the column as each ticket has a unique ID.

My current code:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(E2, 'Shipment Inventory Responses'!D:D), "Yes", "No")
```

I want it do check if the data in 1 cell on the current sheet is present in the D column of another sheet. However, The sheet is empty and it is outputting "Yes". Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to achieve what you want to do:

`=if(countif('Shipment Inventory Responses'!D:D, E2),"Yes","No")`

if you want to use it with an arrayformula for instead of the cell `E2` only you could search in the whole column `E`, you can have the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(E2:E),if(countif('Shipment Inventory Responses'!D:D,E2:E),"Yes","No"),))`